# Formula for biased urn problem with n unique colored balls

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm coding a little game where players can discover new islands with randomly generated properties. Islands have different fertilities (potatoes, linseed, wheat, sugarcane, etc. let $c$ be the number of them) and the player can adjust the count of fertilities the new island will have ($n$). Each fertility has a certain probability of being picked from the random generator. Now I want to show the player the probabilities of each fertility of being picked when he takes a certain $n$.

From my research that seems to be a biased [urn problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem) as I have to pick $n$ out of $m$ colored balls (with $c$ different colors) with different probability without replacement, but in my case it is specialized as each colored ball is unique, so the amount of balls of each color is $1$ ($m=c$). Looking for solutions of that problem showed that it might not be as easy as I thought as it lead me to the [Multivariate Wallenius' noncentral hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallenius%27_noncentral_hypergeometric_distribution), which is far beyond my understanding.

The only viable solution coming to my mind would be a recursive algorithm adding all possible probability paths for each fertility to be picked, but for high $c$ and $n$ this would be soon not usable anymore to compute it in realtime for the player.

Is there any easier solution to that problem regarding the specific case ($m=c$) of my application?